# How to convert string to an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

How can i convert string ids

```
$ids = '8552479333,8552438544,';
```

to look like an array

["8552479333","8552438544"]

I tryed :

```
$ids = (explode(",",$ids,-1));
```

but this gives me :

```
Array ( [0] => 8552479333 [1] => 8552438544)
```

Comment: `$array = implode(',', $string);`

Comment: Explode worked. So I'm confused  as to what  you want

Comment: i want to pass this id-s in post request as a data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very specific way of formatting. You could miss use the json encoding routines to get the exact result you are looking for:

```
<?php
$ids = '8552479333,8552438544,';
$string = json_encode(explode(',', $ids, -1));
var_dump($string);
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(27) "["8552479333","8552438544"]"
```

Comment: alright , i was missing json_encode . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ids = '8552479333,8552438544,';
$ids = json_encode(explode(',', $ids, -1));
print_r($ids);
?>
```